# SVG size controll

Tags: svg

I am new to svg and have a question, how to make svg element to get bigger?
How can i control it?

[image]

player container

[image]

here is my code:

```html
 <div class="player-container">
                        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 97 97" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"
                                opacity="0.153808594">
                                <g id="Car-concept" transform="translate(-193.000000, -733.000000)" fill="#8E95D7">
                                    <g id="Group-10" transform="translate(127.000000, 596.000000)">
                                        <g id="Group-14" transform="translate(66.000000, 137.000000)">
                                            <circle id="Oval" cx="48.5" cy="48.5" r="48.5"></circle>
                                        </g>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </svg>
                        <svg class="moving-outline" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 453 453" fill="none"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <circle cx="226.5" cy="226.5" r="216.5" stroke="#646DBE" stroke-width="10" />
                        </svg>
    
                        <h3 class="time-display">45%</h3>
                    </div>
```

Comment: In this case is enough to change the size of the `.player-container` div. The SVG will take the width of the container. And you don't need `width="100%" height="100%"`

Comment: hey, please take a look at new screenshot player-container widht and height with no padding inside and still svg is not bigger

Comment: I suppose you may need to add your css. Please try first removing `width="100%" height="100%"`